# SignalR with Self-Signed SSL and Self-Host

Tags: ssl, signalr

Tried my luck at research, but so far no joy.

I would like to connect a SignalR javascript client to a self-hosted SignalR Windows Service binding to a self-signed SSL certificate.

My application works quite well over http, but the client repetitively disconnects when the Owin WebApplication starts using https.

Here is what I've done to configure SignalR with SSL.

1. Created a Self-Signed certificate using IIS
2. Imported the certificate into the Trusted Root Certification Authorities in the mmc (not sure if that helped)
3. Ran NETSH command to bind SSL to port 8080

   ```
   netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:8080 certhash=123456f6790a35f4b017b55d09e28f7ebe001bd appid={12345678-db90-4b66-8b01-88f7af2e36bf}
   ```
4. Added code in self-hosted HubConnection instances to add exported SSL like this (though this shouldn't matter because it's the client that cannot connect):

   ```
   if (File.Exists("MyCert.cer") 
       && Settings.GetSetting(Settings.Setting.SrProtocol).Equals("https", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
           connection.AddClientCertificate(X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile("MyCert.cer"));
   ```
5. Starting Owin WebApplication using https (this should create the binding in http.sys)

   ```
   string registerUrl = string.Format("{0}://SOME.WHERE.COM:{1}", Service.Server.SrProtocol, Service.Server.SrPort);
   WebApp.Start<StartUp>(registerUrl);
   ```

In the SignalR 2.0 documentation, it says:

> To start the web server, call WebApplication.Start(endpoint). You should now be able to navigate to endpoint/signalr/hubs in your browser.

When I browse to the URL http://SOME.WHERE.COM:8080/signalr/hubs I am successful receiving the javascript that drives SignalR.

When I browse to the URL https://SOME.WHERE.COM:8080/signalr/hubs I am unsuccessful and I receive "The connection to the server was reset" using FF.

Some additional points I've considered:

- NETSH SHOW indicates the url is registered

  ```
  URL group ID: E300000240000022
  State: Active
  Request queue name: Request queue is unnamed.
  Properties:
      Max bandwidth: inherited
      Max connections: inherited
      Timeouts:
          Timeout values inherited
      Number of registered URLs: 1
      Registered URLs: HTTPS://SOME.WHERE.COM:8080/
  ```
- NETSH SHOW indicates the SSL certificate is bound to 8080:

  ```
  IP:port                 : 0.0.0.0:8080 
  Certificate Hash        : 123456f6790a35f4b017b55d09e28f7ebe001bd
  Application ID          : {12345678-db90-4b66-8b01-88f7af2e36bf} 
  Certificate Store Name  : (null) 
  Verify Client Certificate Revocation    : Enabled
  Verify Revocation Using Cached Client Certificate Only    : Disabled
  Usage Check    : Enabled
  Revocation Freshness Time : 0 
  URL Retrieval Timeout   : 0 
  Ctl Identifier          : (null) 
  Ctl Store Name          : (null) 
  DS Mapper Usage    : Disabled
  Negotiate Client Certificate    : Disabled
  ```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Here's a link to blog post with what's needed to register and create SSL certs and how to set up for SignalR: http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2013/Sep/23/Hosting-SignalR-under-SSLhttps

Comment: @RickStrahl  that link is bad...

Answer (score 20):

I believe its all working for me now.  Here is a run down of the steps I took to get things flowing:

**SSL NOTES**

SSL & SignalR (Owin WebApplication) requires binding a certificate to a port.

1. Use IIS to generate an self-signed cert, this should place the certificate into the LOCAL COMPUTER > Personal > Certificates folder in CERTMGR
2. In CERTMGR shift+drag certificate to LOCAL COMPUTER > Trusted Root Certification Authorities > Certificates folder, which should make a copy of it there
3. Run the following command to bind the SSL certificate to 0.0.0.0:8080

   ```
   netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:8080 certhash=123456f6790a35f4b017b55d09e28f7ebe001bd appid={12345678-db90-4b66-8b01-88f7af2e36bf} 
   netsh http show urlacl > D:\urlacl.txt
   ```

   **Output:**

   ```
   Reserved URL            : https://*:8080/ 
   User: SOMEWHERE\Administrator
   Listen: Yes
   Delegate: No
   SDDL: D:(A;;GX;;;S-1-5-21-138209071-46972887-2260295844-1106)
   ```
4. Run the following NETSH command to reserve all IP addresses for port 8080 to the My Service application ID and service account

   ```
   netsh http add urlacl url=https://*:8080/ user=SOMEWHERE\Administrator listen=yes
   netsh http show sslcert > D:\sslcert.txt
   ```

   **Output:**

   ```
   IP:port                 : 0.0.0.0:8080 
   Certificate Hash        : 123456f6790a35f4b017b55d09e28f7ebe001bd
   Application ID          : {12345678-db90-4b66-8b01-88f7af2e36bf} 
   Certificate Store Name  : (null) 
   Verify Client Certificate Revocation    : Enabled
   Verify Revocation Using Cached Client Certificate Only    : Disabled
   Usage Check    : Enabled
   Revocation Freshness Time : 0 
   URL Retrieval Timeout   : 0 
   Ctl Identifier          : (null) 
   Ctl Store Name          : (null) 
   DS Mapper Usage    : Disabled
   Negotiate Client Certificate    : Disabled
   ```
5. Update the MyServices.exe.config file to use https protocol (These are appSetting keys used to dynamically set the protocol and port of SignalR when My Service starts)

   ```
   <add key="SrProtocol" value="https" />
   <add key="SrPort" value="8080" />
   ```
6. Start the My Service using the NETSTAT START command
7. Run the following NETSH command to show the service state is occupying the registered url

   ```
   netsh http show servicestate > D:\servicestate.txt
   ```

   **Output:**

   ```
   Server session ID: C300000320000039
   Version: 2.0
   State: Active
   Properties:
       Max bandwidth: 4294967295
       Timeouts:
           Entity body timeout (secs): 120
           Drain entity body timeout (secs): 120
           Request queue timeout (secs): 120
           Idle connection timeout (secs): 120
           Header wait timeout (secs): 120
           Minimum send rate (bytes/sec): 150
   URL groups:
   URL group ID: C600000340000138
       State: Active
       Request queue name: Request queue is unnamed.
       Properties:
           Max bandwidth: inherited
           Max connections: inherited
           Timeouts:
               Timeout values inherited
           Number of registered URLs: 1
           Registered URLs:
               HTTPS://*:8080/
   ```

My application does NOT depend on IIS, but once I used IIS to temporarily create a port binding to my SSL certificate, my application started to work, and I was able to inspect the NETSH servicestate to see how IIS does it.  I have since dropped the IIS binding and ran through the setup notes, and still have success.

My Owing startup looks somethign like this:

```
private void configureMessaging()
{
    string registerUrl = string.Format("{0}://*:{1}", Service.Server.SrProtocol, Service.Server.SrPort);

    try
    {
#if DEBUG
        //System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
#endif
        //  Starts an owin web application to host SignalR, using the protocol and port defined.
        WebApp.Start<StartUp>(registerUrl);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logger.Logs.Log(string.Format("Failed to configure messaging.  Exception: {0}", ex.RecurseInnerException()), LogType.Error);            

        if (ex is HttpListenerException || ex.InnerException is HttpListenerException)
        {
            try
            {
                Process p = new Process();
                p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                p.StartInfo.FileName = "netsh.exe";
                p.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("netsh http delete urlacl url={0}"
                    , registerUrl
                    );
                p.Start();
                p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
                p.WaitForExit();
            }
            catch (Exception exP)
            {
                Logger.Logs.Log(string.Format("Failed to delete urlacl {0}.  Exception: {1}"
                    , registerUrl
                    , exP.RecurseInnerException()
                    )
                    , LogType.Error
                    )
                    ;

                retries = 5;
            }
        }

    if (retries < 5)
    {
        retries++;

        Logger.Logs.Log(string.Format("Attempting to configure messaging again.  Attempt No. {0}", retries), LogType.Warn);

        Thread.Sleep(1000);

        configureMessaging();
    }
    else
        Logger.Logs.Log(string.Format("Exceeded total number of retries to configure messaging.", retries), LogType.Error);

    }
```

}

And self-hosted HubConnetion instances look like this:

```
    public IHubProxy MyHubProxy
    {
        get
        {
            if (this._MyHubProxy == null)
            {
                var connection = new HubConnection(string.Format("{0}://{1}:{2}/"
                    , Settings.GetSetting(Settings.Setting.SrProtocol)
                    , MyHub.GetLocalhostFqdn(null)
                    , Settings.GetSetting(Settings.Setting.SrPort)
                    )
                    )
                    ;
                this._MyHubProxy = connection.CreateHubProxy("MyHub");

                if (File.Exists("My.cer")
                    && Settings.GetSetting(Settings.Setting.SrProtocol).Equals("https", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                    connection.AddClientCertificate(X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile("My.cer"));

                connection.Start().Wait();
            }

            return this._MyHubProxy;
        }
    }
```

There is a little more code here than relevant, but hopefully it may be of help!

Comment: "My application does NOT depend on IIS, but once I used IIS to temporarily create a port binding to my SSL certificate, my application started to work, and I was able to inspect the NETSH servicestate to see how IIS does it. I have since dropped the IIS binding and ran through the setup notes, and still have success." So you say that someone needs IIS to setup the ssl cert first and then the ssl works in with selfhosting in Owin? That would be stupid because Owin should be decoupled from any web server... Would you mark  your answer as a solution 5 months later having more experience now?

Comment: Right, I am not proposing IIS be a part of the process, it's just something I tried to get to the bottom of it.  Also, I plan to circle back to SSL in my next release and will be happy to mark this as a solution when I review it, patience requested ;) Thanks!