# Establishing a SignalR connection when using a self-signed certificate

Tags: ssl, signalr, self-signed

I have a self-hosted WebAPI web service using a self-signed certificate.  I am successfully able to communicate with the web service controller actions from other applications using the URL:

```
https://localhost:5150/...
```

Note that I have successfully bound the self-signed certificate to port 5150 and reserved the port for all IPs for my application, both by using the appropriate *netsh* commands.

I am trying to integrate a SignalR hub into this web service.  I configure the hub, with CORS support, using the following in my startup code:

```
// Configure the SignalR hub that will talk to the browser
        appBuilder.Map("/signalr", map =>
        {
            map.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);

            HubConfiguration hubConfig = new HubConfiguration();
            hubConfig.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
            hubConfig.EnableJavaScriptProxies = false;

            map.RunSignalR(hubConfig);
        });
```

I am starting up my HTTP listener, which is/was also used for Web API by this:

```
_webApp = WebApp.Start<Startup>(baseUrl);
```

where the baseUrl is

```
https://+:5150/.
```

My SignalR initialization code, in my Angular controller is:

```
var initialize = function () {

    //Getting the connection object
    connection = $.hubConnection("/signalr", { useDefaultPath: false });

    // Url signalr scripts should hit back on the server
    connection.url = ENV.SIGNALR.protocol + '://' + ENV.SIGNALR.server + ':' + ENV.SIGNALR.port + '/' + ENV.SIGNALR.url;

    // Turn on client-side logging
    connection.logging = ENV.SIGNALR.logging;

    // Get proxy based on Hub name (must be camel-case)
    proxy = connection.createHubProxy('dashboardHub');

    // Setup event handlers for messages we get from the server.
    proxy.on('rxDiagnosticMessage', function (msg) {
        //console.log('Received rxDiagnosticMessage');
        $rootScope.$broadcast("rx-diagnostic-message", msg);
    });

    //Starting connection
    connection.start()
        .done(function () { console.log('SignalR connection started'); })
        .fail(function (err) { console.log('SignalR connection failed - ' + err); });

    // Display errors to console
    connection.error(function (err) {
        console.log('SignalR error - ' + err);
    });
};
```

When the connection to the hub is attempted, I get the following error:

```
15:04:43 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] SignalR: Auto detected cross domain url. jquery.signalR-2.1.0.js:81
[15:04:43 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] SignalR: Client subscribed to hub 'dashboardhub'. jquery.signalR-2.1.0.js:81
[15:04:43 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] SignalR: Negotiating with 'https://localhost:5150/signalr/negotiate?clientProtocol=1.4&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22dashboardhub%22%7D%5D'. jquery.signalR-2.1.0.js:81
GET https://localhost:5150/signalr/negotiate?clientProtocol=1.4&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22dashboardhub%22%7D%5D&_=1407524683014 net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE jquery-2.1.1.js:8623
SignalR error - Error: Error during negotiation request. AppSignalR.js:43
SignalR connection failed - Error: Error during negotiation request. AppSignalR.js:39
[15:04:43 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] SignalR: Stopping connection.
```

Note the **net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE** during the SignalR connection negotiation.

*Strange* thing...if I run Fiddler2 then the connection works! (Is Fiddler serving up a nice certificate to my web app / SignalR?)

I suspect this is due to the certificate being self-signed (cert in Personal, cert authority in Trusted).  In WCF and WebAPI clients I always intercept the authority errors and bypass the error:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = ((sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true);
```

Is there something similar that needs to be done in the SignalR client in my Angular application?  Or should this just work?

Note that I have seen this thread - [SignalR with Self-Signed SSL and Self-Host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18150758/signalr-with-self-signed-ssl-and-self-host....but) still does not work for me.

Answer (score -2):

You cannot use localhost with SSL, you need absolute HostName in URL.

Look at the ISSUED BY and ISSUED TO field in the Certificate you created, ISSUED BY needs to be part of the "Trusted Publisher" list on your machine(machine that is accessing the webpage using browser), and ISSUED TO needs to be part of your URL .i.e. the certificate has been issued to you and only you. So if your ISSUED TO  field has value "HOSTNAME.DOMAINNAME" where HOSTNAMe is hostName of the machine and DomainName is the Domain of the machine where the web site is hosted, then you need to access your SITE using the same name i.e 
.

Hope this helps.

Comment: and also not true.. any cert can contain cn=localhost or even cn=127.0.0.1