# Adding real time functionality to my Xamarin app chat is throwing System.InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, signalr, chat

I created a Xamarin app with a chat and a API to store it's data, every 3 minutes the mobile app makes a request to the api for the chat messages.

I decided to use SignalR as was suggested in the comments:

-Added it to my CongifureService as shown:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {           
        services.AddDbContext<HostelContext>(opt =>
           opt.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("HostelContext")));

        services.AddCors();
        services.AddControllers();

        services.AddAuthentication("BasicAuthentication")
            .AddScheme<AuthenticationSchemeOptions, BasicAuthenticationHandler>("BasicAuthentication", null);

        services.AddScoped<IUsersService, UsersService>();
        services.AddScoped<IConversationsService, ConversationsService>();
        services.AddScoped<IMessagesService, MessagesService>();

        // Register the Swagger generator, defining 1 or more Swagger documents
        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "HostelApi", Version = "v1" });             
        });

        services.AddSignalR();
    }
```

-Added Endpoint to Configure as shown:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {                
            endpoints.MapControllers();
            endpoints.MapHub<ChatHub>("/chatHub");
        });
```

-Added Class to my api project in new folder called Hub

-This is the Hub class:

```
//[Authorize]    
public class ChatHub : Hub
{                
    public async Task SendMessage(Message message)
    {
        //await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", message);
        await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage" + message.ConversationId, message);
        //await Clients.Users(destinationUserIdList).SendAsync("ReceiveMessage" + message.ConversationId, message);
    }
}
```

In my Xamarin app:

-Added Hub Service:

-This is the Hub Service Class:

```
class HubService : IHubService
{
    public HubConnection HubConnection { get; }
    public HubService()
    {
        HubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
            .WithUrl($"https://10.0.2.2:5001/chatHub")
            .Build();
    }

    public async Task Connect()
    {
        await HubConnection.StartAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    public async Task Disconnect()
    {
        await HubConnection.StopAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    public async Task SendMessage(Message message)
    {            
        await HubConnection.InvokeAsync("SendMessage", message).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```

-Connect to Hub when app starts after login:

```
public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();                   

        MasterBehavior = MasterBehavior.Popover;

        //should be home page
        MenuPages.Add((int)MenuItemType.Home, (NavigationPage)Detail);

        HubService.Connect().ConfigureAwait(true);            
    }
```

-Close connection on log out

-When sending a message i call SendMessage method:

```
await HubService.SendMessage(message).ConfigureAwait(true);
            OutGoingText = string.Empty;
            Messages.Add(message);
```

The Problem now is when i send a message and gets to:

```
public async Task SendMessage(Message message)
    {            
        await HubConnection.InvokeAsync("SendMessage", message).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
```

throws this:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'The 'InvokeCoreAsync' method cannot be called if the connection is not active'
```

Already tried with HubService.Connect().Wait() but app stays in a loop

Can anyone help me with this?? @Nick Kovalsky...

Best Regards

Comment: are you sure the client is establishing the Connection before you call Send?

Comment: When i call "connect" if i use "wait" on it, the app freezes and i have to restart it.
I guess this means that no connection is happening, and i don't know why :S
The api endpoint for the Hub is there, if i use the url on a browser i get "connection id required" so it means that api is not the problem. 
Why is the connection not happening??? I have no idea :S

Comment: don't do network operations on your UI thread.  Have you tested the hub url on the device/emulator browser instead of a desktop browser?  Are you using a self-signed cert?

Comment: I just tested it and warns me that connection isn't secure, i make proceed anyway and appears "Connection ID required" like in my pc browser. I've other api endpoints which i can reach with this Xamarin app, it is just the hub i can't connect. About certificate, i added one when i created the api don't know which certificate was i believe it was a self-signed, because i needed for my browser be able to reach the api.

Comment: I have no idea if SignalR will work with a self-signed cert.

Comment: Thanks @Jason I found this post:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18150758/signalr-with-self-signed-ssl-and-self-host

I guess it can work but I don't understand it very well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find out the problem!

The problem was calling "HubService.Connect().ConfigureAwait(true);" which is an async method inside a constructor, so it couldn't have the await.

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();                   

    MasterBehavior = MasterBehavior.Popover;

    //should be home page
    MenuPages.Add((int)MenuItemType.Home, (NavigationPage)Detail);

    HubService.Connect().ConfigureAwait(true);            
}
```

Solved be moving the call "HubService.Connect().ConfigureAwait(true);" to App.xaml.cs and put it inside "OnStart()" method:

```
protected override async void OnStart()
    {
        await HubService.Connect().ConfigureAwait(true);
    }
```

Thank you all guys!